# Jquery + Add Up Checkbox Values

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page with a number of checkboxes. 
Each Checkbox is for a different item (virtual Rose) and rose has a different value.
I have put the value of the rose into the value="" of the checkbox.
I need to add up the total value of the ticked checkboxes - eg: 100, 230 etc.
The only other factor is I need to only add up checkboxes with the class "giftsRosesCheckBox".

```
<table id="tableGiftsWhiteRose"><tr>
  <td colspan="2">White Rose</td></tr><tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="giftsRosesCheckBox" value="100"/></td>
  <td class="credits">100 credits</td> 
</tr></table>

<table  id="tableGiftsRedRose"><tr>
  <td colspan="2">Red Rose</td></tr><tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="giftsRosesCheckBox" value="130"/></td>
  <td class="credits">130 credits</td>      
</tr></table>

<table><tr>
  <td colspan="2">Stunning Red Rose</td></tr><tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="giftsRosesCheckBox" value="150"/></td>
  <td class="credits">150 credits</td>      
</tr></table>
```

I'm really not sure how to do this so a push in the right direction would be great.

thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".giftsRosesCheckBox").click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".giftsRosesCheckBox:checked").each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    });
    alert(total);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You could loop over the checkboxes and add their values.

```
var total = 0;
$(':checkbox:checked.giftsRosesCheckBox').each(function() {
    total += +this.value;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76S9c/).

If you didn't have to support older browsers (or shim `reduce()`), you could do it in a more functional way...

```
var total = $(':checkbox:checked.giftsRosesCheckBox')
            .get()
            .reduce(function(total, checkbox) {
                 return total + +checkbox.value;
             }, 0);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tRSKK/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var total =0;
$('input[type=checkbox].giftsRosesCheckBox, input[checked=checked].giftsRosesCheckBox').each(function(){
total += this.val();
});
```