# Get value from checkbox with js and jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="totalPrice">Value</span>
    <span id="productId1">1000</span>
    <span id="productId2">2222</span>
    <span id="productId3">2222</span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2"/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="3"/>
    <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add"/>
</body>
</html>
```

If I click on the checkbox, then I get its value and concatenate. As a result, I get the id for the span from which I want to take the value and sum it up. After that, display the entire amount in span

this is my js code:

```
$(function(){
  
  var totalPrice = $('#totalPrice');
  var boxes = $('input[type=checkbox]')
  var totalPriceNow = 0;

    boxes.click(function() {
      totalPriceNow = 0;
      boxes.each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
          var productId = 'productId';
          productId += this.value;
          var productPrice = $('#' + 'productId').text();
          totalPriceNow += parseInt(productPrice);
        }
      });

      totalPrice.text(totalPriceNow);
  });
})
```

Comment: Any code attempt for javascript?

Comment: SO is not a coding service...  Contributors expect an attempt from you about which it is possible to give explanations why your attempt failed.

Comment: And I found two duplicates for your question: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718926/adding-checkbox-values-using-jquery) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382622/jquery-add-up-checkbox-values)

Comment: I added everything I have) Don't swear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever any checkbox is `change` you can loop through all checkboxes which is checked and add your sum to some variable and finally add this value to your `totalPrice`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  var totalPriceNow = 0;
  //loop through checked checkboxes
  $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    var productId = 'productId' + this.value;
    totalPriceNow += parseInt($('#' + productId).text().trim()); //get text
  })
  $('#totalPrice').text(totalPriceNow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<span id="totalPrice">Value</span>
<span id="productId1">1000</span>
<span id="productId2">2222</span>
<span id="productId3">2222</span>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />
<input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// listen for change event on any "selected" checkbox
  $(document).on('change', '[name="selected"]', function () {
    // get selected checkbox values as array of numbers
    var selectedValues = $('[name="selected"]:checked').map(function () {
      // convert value from string to number
      return Number($(this).val());
    }).get();
    
    // add prices together to get total price
    var totalPrice = selectedValues.reduce(function (total, price) {
      return total + price;
    }, 0);
    
    $('#totalPrice').html(totalPrice);
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="totalPrice">0</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="3">
</body>
</html>
```